# Test in Spring boot @MockMvcTest the MockHttpServletResponse always return a empty body

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm using mockito to make unit test in my controller, but when I execute the test I have status 200 with an empty body in MockHttpServletResponse. I would like to test the body response with jsonPath from MockMvcResultMatchers but I can't do it while the body is empty.

Here is Controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("automotor")
public class AutomotorController {
  @Autowired private IAutomotorService automotorService;
  @Autowired private Informacion informacion;

  @GetMapping(path = "/propiedad", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public List<AutomotorDTO> consultaPorPropietario() throws ElementNotFoundException {
    return automotorService.consultarPorPropietario(
        informacion.getTipoUsuario(), informacion.getUsuario());
  }
}
```

This is my test class, I try do debug but it doesn't show problems and now I don't know what to do, I try visit similar posts but nothing works.

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = AutomotorController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class AutomotorControllerTest {

    @Autowired private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean private AutomotorService automotorService;
    @MockBean private Informacion informacion;
    @InjectMocks private AutomotorController automotorController;

    private String url = "/automotor";
    private AutomotorInDTO test;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        test = new AutomotorInDTO();
        test.setIdAutomotor(Long.valueOf(123456789));
        test.setPlaca("ABC123");
    }
    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource(value = {"C:1001231234"}, delimiter = ':')
    @DisplayName("Obtener automotor por propietario exitoso")
    void consultaPorPropietario(String tipo, String numero) throws Exception {
        List<AutomotorDTO> automotorDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
        automotorDTOList.add(initListAutomotor());
        //when(automotorService.consultarPorPropietario(tipo, numero)).thenReturn(automotorDTOList);
        doReturn(automotorDTOList).when(automotorService).consultarPorPropietario(tipo, numero);
        ResultActions response = mockMvc.perform(get(url + "/propiedad")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                        .andDo(print())
                        .andExpect(status().isOk())
                        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.placa").exists()) //Line 78
                        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.placa").value("ABC123"));
    }
}
```

and this is my object test:

```
private AutomotorDTO initListAutomotor() {
        AutomotorDTO automotorDTO = new AutomotorDTO() {
            @Override
            public String getPlaca() {
                return "ABC123";
            }

            @Override
            public String getClase() {
                return "CAMIONETA";
            }

            @Override
            public String getMarca() {
                return "RENAULT";
            }

            @Override
            public String getLinea() {
                return "DUSTER OROCH";
            }

            @Override
            public String getColor() {
                return "ROJO";
            }

            @Override
            public String getEstado() {
                return "ACTIVO";
            }

            @Override
            public Long getIdAutomotor() {
                return Long.valueOf(123456789);
            }
        };
        return automotorDTO;
    }
```

Comment: I believe the issue comes from the anonymous class `new AutomotorDTO() {..}`, I assume your are using jackson for serialization, and it does not support anonymous class. Try using a proper object instance, like you do `new AutomotorDTOImpl("ABC123", ... );`